# Issue uploading a big size file with Tomcat9

Tags: tomcat, file-upload, genexus

I am developing a WebApp in GeneXus 17 U10 to upload reports in txt and impact the SQL database. The big problem is that when I upload a +10 GB file, it disappears, i mean, at the end of the upload, the final size of the file in the WebApp is 0 KB.
I've tried changing the "max-file-size" and the problem continue.

Please, can anybody help!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: i'm using Navicat Premium 15

Comment: Yes, but which database do you connect to?

Comment: oh, sorry, i'm using a local db

Answer (score 0):

According to Tomcat documentation, you can increase Tomcat server upload file size limit by the editing webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml configuration file and search for the below content.

```
<multipart-config>
   <max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>
   <max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>
   <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
```

Edit max-file-size and max-request-size and increase it as your requirement. These values are defined in bytes and the default value is set to 50 MB.

¿Have you changed the value of max-request-size? ¿What User Control are you using to upload the file?